# Undefined data (sometimes data)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to read an `Array` inside my `FireStore` document. I want to render the items inside this `Array` in a component through using `.map()`.

Sometimes, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error. What could be causing it and how can I ensure that it doesn't happen.

```
interface Product {
    summary: string;
    details: string;
    product: string;
    benefit: Array<string>;
}

function ProductInfo({ product }: { product: Product }) {
    console.log("Product:",product.summary);
    product.benefit.forEach((item) => { //triggers exception sometimes
        console.log(item)
    })
}
```

In a different component, this is how I populate the data and pass it to the component above:

```
function ProductDetails({ match }: RouteComponentProps<TParams>) {
    const [product, setProduct]: any = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await db.collection("Products").doc(match.params.id).get();
                console.log('response', response.data());
                let data: any = { title: 'not found' };
                if (response.exists) {
                    data = response.data();
                }
                setProduct(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <ProductInfo product={product} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm learning React with TypeScript so I'm still trying to get the hang of things. I'm confused as to why it works sometimes and does not at other instances. `product.summary` gets rendered all the time though. Thank you

**EDIT**
From debugging, I think I seem to have found the issue:
If I test with:

```
const [product, setProduct]: any = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await db.collection("Products").doc("flex-crm").get();
                console.log('response', response.data());
                let data: any = { title: 'not found' };
                if (response.exists) {
                    data = response.data();
                }
                setProduct(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    console.log("Data: ", product)
```

I get 3 lines of output in the console (instead of 2). I get

```
Data: undefined
response {...}
Data: {...}
```

My prop is using the `Data:undefined` instance when the component is rendered. How can I update it to use the fetched data?

Comment: When `!response.exists` then `product === { title: 'not found' }` which does not have the property `benefit` to map. Your sample is also a bit confusing because `.map` is never called, and you initialise `product` as an array but you seem to be expecting it as an object in `ProjectInfo`.

Comment: Moving the `setProduct` to where `response` exists doesn't seem to change it. Couple of refreshes, appears, some it doesn't. --I see what you mean, the variables are a little confusing. Let me change `product` to `currentItem`.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't always immediately throw an error to be honest because `product.benefit.forEach` should always throw a TypeError when the component mounts if you are initialising `product` as an array.

Comment: You mean in `useState([])`? I need a products array since I'm loading all the products from somewhere and then dynamically loading a `details` page based on the selected product. Is there some other way I should go about it?

Comment: @lawrence-witt I think I found the issue, please see the edit I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `setProduct(data);` inside the `if` condition. Maybe for some products response is not present and you are still setting `data` which will be `undefined` in that case.

```
                if (response.exists) {
                    data = response.data();
                    setProduct(data);
                }
```

Comment: This makes sense. But I still get the same problem. I'm going to try to make a different `collection` with one `document` to test if I can read the `Array` in that `document`

Comment: Answer for your EDIT: you are seeing `Date: ...` twice in console output because `setProduct` will cause a re-render of the component. Which will execute `console.log` again which is outside the effect.

Comment: If it's causing a re-render, then how come the second `console.log` shows the data, but said data is not reflected in the component? So the issue is in how i'm setting it?

Comment: I just figured it out. The problem was in how I was setting it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `product?.summary.map(...)`.
Probably this will help you.

~Also why did you use `response.data()` i could not get it, shouldn't it be `response.data`?

Comment: `response.data` gave me a totally different set of data than the one with the parenthesis. I thought it was strange too

Comment: I've not used Firestore before personally but from reading other questions that seems to be the standard way to access the returned data.

Comment: Aah maybe, I also did not work much of firestore/firebase.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem is ` <ProductInfo product={product} />`. `{product}` is null it seems. I'm not quite sure how to fix it